# Help with grub-update?

Tags: grub2, disk, system

Good Morning.
Sorry, bit of a newbie question.
I have added a second hard disk to my Ubuntu system with a separate bootable Mint partition.
When I run update-grub as sudo to include new partition/OS I get:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESgj3.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: Welcome! The line should be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i cmdline /etc/default/grub`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @guillermochamorro That's one of two possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

You should see both of these lines near the top of this file. Figure out which one is partially missing text, and correct it.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`.

`sudo update-grub` # update grub

Comment: Thank you all. Syntax error found in /etc/default/grub that I completely did not see, problem solved. Thanks aagain.

Comment: @TedJackson Please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @TedJackson Status please...